# Why does this test always return false?

Tags: c++, variables, if-statement, scope

Please ignore the context of this code. The idea was the 
 function named `shop()` would take the two parameters 
 (`money_in_pocket`, `age`) and determine if these values would 
 let them into a Rolex store. However, even when the 
 parameters meet the requirements of the if statement in 
 `shop()`, the program proceeds to output "Leave!"- 
 meaning leave the store.

As you may have noticed, I'm new to the language, so any 
 help  would be much appreciated.

I've tried making the parameters far larger than the `if` 
 statements asks for them to be. This outputted "leave!", so 
I tried parameters that did not meet the requirements and 
 the same output was displayed...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class rolex{

   public:
      bool shop(int x, int y){
         if((x >= 5000 && y>= 18)||(x>=5000 && y<18)){
            bool enterence = true;
         }else{
            bool enterence = false;
         };
         return enterence;
      }
   private:
      bool enterence;
};

int main()
{
   rolex objj;

   if( objj.shop(5000, 18) == true){
      cout<<"you may enter"<<endl;
   }else{
      cout<<"LEAVE"<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the variables `bool enterence` are defined locally inside the scope of the `if`. Thus, the returned value is the class member `enterence`, which is unititialized, and happens to be false in your case.

Comment: `bool enterence = true;` and `bool enterence = false;` are both using local variables `enterence` that hide the memer variable ultimately returned. remove both `bool` leading types from those lines. Frankly, I don't see the sense of the member variable in the first place (and its not even initialized properly, so this also suffers from undefined-behavior regardless). The entire `shop` member could just be written as `return (x >= 5000);`

Comment: Do you have compiler warnings enabled?

Comment: works perfect now, thank you very much! Also, i wasn't trying to be efficient because as i am new i am currently trying utilize as many features of the language as possible

Answer (score 5):

In the if statement

```
     if((x >= 5000 && y>= 18)||(x>=5000 && y<18)){
        bool enterence = true;
     }else{
        bool enterence = false;
     };
```

you declared two local variables that will not be alive after exiting the if statement.

So the data member `rolex::enterence` is not initialized and has indeterminate value.

Change the if statement like

```
     if((x >= 5000 && y>= 18)||(x>=5000 && y<18)){
        enterence = true;
     }else{
        enterence = false;
     };
```

Take into account that the condition in the if statement is equivalent to

```
     if( x >= 5000 ){
```

You could just write instead of the if statement

```
enterence = x >= 5000;
```

or

```
rolex::enterence = x >= 5000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple edit of your program that works as you intended:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class rolex {

    private:
        bool entrance;

    public:
      bool shop(int x, int y) {
          if(x >= 5000 && y>= 18) {
              entrance = true;
          } else {
              entrance = false;
          }
          return entrance;
      }
};


int main() {
    rolex obj;

    if(obj.shop(5000, 18) == true) {
        cout << "you may enter" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "LEAVE" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```